# File object to Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, file, beautifulsoup

What is difference between these two?

```
data = open(fil_name, 'r').read()
datap = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')

with open(fil_name, 'r') as openfh:
    soup = BeautifSoup(openfh, 'lxml')
```

Which is relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass in an open filehandle to `BeautifulSoup`:

```
with open(fil_name, 'r') as openfh:
    soup = BeautifSoup(openfh, 'lxml')
```

Your code, on the other hand, is passing in a string; it doesn't matter where that string came from. Your code read it from a file, but it could just as easily have been read from a network connection (loaded from a URL, for example).

See the [Making the soup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup):

> To parse a document, pass it into the `BeautifulSoup` constructor. You
>   can pass in a string or an open filehandle:
>
> ```
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>
> soup = BeautifulSoup(open("index.html"))
>
> soup = BeautifulSoup("<html>data</html>")
> ```

Comment: I don´t understand it actually

Comment: @karu: you don't understand what exactly? The difference between a file object and the data you read from it?

Comment: @See I have a file, Open it using open function, I need to pass the file to Beautiful Soup so that I can process it

Comment: @karu: `openfh` is an open file object. I used the `with` statement to close the file object again when done with it, but it is the same as if I used `openfh = open(fil_name, 'r')`.

Comment: @karu: Your code, on the other hand, calls `.read()` on the open file object, returning all the string contents of the file, not the file object itself.

Comment: so with statement, we are passing file object to Beautiful Soup constructor right ?

Comment: Which one is required for Beautiful Soup ?

Comment: @karu: No, the `with` statement uses the file object as a context manager. All that it does is ensure that `openfh.close()` is called when that block of code is done. It is a way to make sure the file is neatly closed whatever happens.

Comment: @karu: `with` is not required for BeautifulSoup. Passing in the file object itself is.

Comment: @karu: Did you ever think about reading the [official Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)?